# Ubuntu 10.4 LTS freezes all the time

Tags: 10.04

did a parallel install of 10.4 LTS today, used jaunty (9.04) until now. Had no problems with the system, just out of date.

The new installed system freezes every few minutes, even if I just start the system (auto log on). I use the INTEL GMA 950 onboard graphic. I heard of problems with some kernels with this chipsset, newer kernels should have this issue fixed - but I had a stable system using jaunty...

Is there a solution other than stick to 9.04?

TIA

Comment: There are several versions of Ubuntu you can try. 11.04, 11.10, and in 4 months, 12.04

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

There is a bunch of newer kernels backported into Lucid's repositories.

```
~$ apt-cache search linux-image-generic-lts
linux-image-generic-lts-backport-maverick - Generic Linux kernel image 2.6.35-xx
linux-image-generic-lts-backport-natty - Generic Linux kernel image 2.6.38-xx
linux-image-generic-lts-backport-oneiric - Generic Linux kernel image 3.0.0-xx
```

Do you know in which kernel the problem you referred to has been fixed?

Answer (score 0):

10.04 does use an older kernel. As bodhi.zazen said, you can upgrade to a later Ubuntu version. This will also update the kernel, hopefully fixing the issue.

Comment: I upgraded the kernel to 2.6.32-37, did not change anything. Problem with updating to 11.04 or newer is, that there might be problems with parallel booting older systems due to changes in grub2. For now, I'll use 9.04 and test on a different hard drive - never touch a running...

Comment: grub2, as far as I know, is fully backwards-compatible. The most recent kernel version is 3.0.0. mikewhatever made a helpful post - if you don't want to upgrade, try installing one of those kernels.